# jQuery: Selecting the currently selected element (example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

For example, I have something like:

```
<div data-url="http://google.com">
  <iframe src=""></iframe>
</div>
<div data-url="http://facebook.com">
  <iframe src=""></iframe>
</div>
<div data-url="http://youtube.com">
  <iframe src=""></iframe>
</div>

<script>
$('div iframe').attr('src',$(this).parent().attr('data-url'));
</script>
```

I want to delay the loading of the iframe using jQuery. I want to set the iframe's "src" to be the same as its parent's "data-url". How can I do that?

Or, is there another way to delay the loading of an iframe until everything else loads?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. It turns out I have to use .each()

$('div iframe').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).parent().attr('data-url'));
  });

Answer (score 1):

In your code `this` is actually the window object. You want to wrap this code in a `each` method. (Also, notice how this code doesn't call $(this) twice)

```
$('div iframe').each(function(ev){
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.attr('src', elem.parent().data('url')); 
});
```

Comment: if that's in $(document).ready(function() { ... }) that should work.  Also, you should use elem.data('url') instead of attr('data-url') to be more consistent with modern JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you add the data-url to the src:

```
 $('div').each(function(){
        $(this).children('iframe').attr('src',$(this).attr('data-url'));
    });
```